# Android video format

Tags: android, video, h.264

We want to create a video that can be played on all Android devices.
How should we specify the format of the video, such that it will play on pretty much all Android devices?

The production company that we are working with has proposed:

```
Container = QuickTime Movie
Frame Size = 1280 x 720
Frame Rate = 30 fps
Codec = ProRes HQ (if alpha channel is needed, use ProRes 4444) 
Audio = PCM - 48khz, 16bit (if needed)
```

I *think* that is completely wrong.  They clearly know nothing whatever about Android, and are merely proposing things that have worked for them with iOS.  .Mov files don't play on Android at all.

I think this is the universal format, including specifically "will play on Android":

```
container format = .mp4 (MPEG4) 
codec =  "H.263", 
audio codec = AAC-LC
```

Can anyone who has practical experience of video on Android give their guidance on this?  Thank you,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is quite a bit of detail [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#recommendations).

Summary:

- H.264 Baseline Profile, 480 x 360 px, 30 fps, 500 Kbps
- AAC-LC, Stereo, 128 Kbps

Comment: Thanks for the links, Paul.  I had read that page (all of it, not just the two sections you linked to) previously, but found some of it confusing.   What does "•" mean in the codec columns?

Comment: Bullet means supported, but only on certain platforms if one is given in parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

1280 * 720 is a big resolution for the any android devices and it will not work in all the devices...I use 640*480 , and its working in all the devices I will check..
here is my code

this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    this.mediaRecorder.setCamera(this.camera);

```
this.mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
this.mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
this.mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);


this.mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(10000);


this.mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(this.initFile().getAbsolutePath());
this.mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
this.mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
 this.mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(640,480); 
 this.mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(12); 





try {
    this.mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(this.cameraPreview.getHolder().getSurface());
    this.mediaRecorder.prepare();




    // start the actual recording
    // throws IllegalStateException if not prepared
    this.mediaRecorder.start();
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.recording, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // enable the stop button by indicating that we are recording
    this.toggleButtons(true);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.wtf(TAG, "Failed to prepare MediaRecorder", e);
    Toast.makeText(this,"record nathi thatu...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    this.releaseMediaRecorder();
}
```

}

Comment: I don't think he's asking about recording video on the device. Rather, what format/encoding will be universally supported by all Android devices.

Comment: Yes, Paul's clarification is correct -- we are hiring an art house to create the video to our spec.  However, given their appalling ignorance about the highest volume platform in the computer industry, I am now wondering.   Perhaps they know more about art than they do about Android.   Thanks everyone -- very helpful.